# In the following implementation of static_strlen, why are the & and parentheses around str necessary?

Tags: c++, templates, pass-by-reference

If I change the type to `const char str[Len]`, I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘static_strlen(const char [5])’
```

Am I correct that `static_strlen` expects an array of const char *references*? My understanding is that arrays are passed as pointers anyway, so what need is there for the elements to be references?  Or is that interpretation completely off-the-mark?

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t Len>
size_t
static_strlen(const char (&str)[Len])
{
  return Len - 1;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << static_strlen("oyez") << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the function parameter is a reference to an array of `Len` const chars. That's how the function knows the length (assuming the last byte is a NUL terminator, hence the -1). The parentheses are there precisely to stop it being what you think it is.

Actually there's no such thing in C++ as an array of references, so it couldn't be what you think it is even without the parens. I guess (but am not sure) that the need for the parens is just for consistency with other similar type definitions, such as pointers to arrays:

```
void fn(const char *a[3]); // parameter a is of type const char**, the 3 is ignored.
void fn(const char (*a)[3]; // parameter a is a pointer to an array of 3 const chars.
```

That example also illustrates why an array is not a pointer. Predict the output of the following program, and then run it:

```
#include <iostream>

void fn(const char (*a)[3]) {
    std::cout << sizeof(a) << "\n" << sizeof(*a) << "\n";
}

void fn2(const char *a[3]) {
    std::cout << sizeof(a) << "\n" << sizeof(*a) << "\n";
}

int main() {
    const char a[3] = {};
    const char **b = 0;
    fn(&a);
    fn2(b);
}

#if 0 
// error: declaration of `a' as array of references
void fn3(const char & a[3]) {
    std::cout << sizeof(a) << "\n" << sizeof(*a) << "\n";
}
#endif
```

Comment: Ok, that helps a lot.  But why a reference?  Isn't the name of an array parameter really just a pointer to the first element?

Comment: @Ben: **No.** Pointers point to an address, arrays are arrays. The name can *decay* to a pointer, but an array is not a pointer. Note my comment on the question: you cannot pass an array "by pointer". You can pass a pointer to the first element, sure, but you aren't passing the array.

Comment: @Steve, in your fn example, is a different value pushed onto the argument stack in those two cases?  Does the distinction exist outside the type system?

Comment: @Ben: what two cases? One takes (a pointer to) `a`, and the other takes the value of `b`, which is 0. So yes, a different value is pushed onto the stack. There's nothing directly related to `a` that can be passed into `fn2` - it takes a pointer to a pointer to a char. `a` can decay into a pointer-to-char, but if it does so then the resulting `const char*` is an rvalue, and you can't take a pointer to an rvalue.

Comment: @Steve, thanks for the demonstration.  Out of curiosity, what is the value `&a` that you're passing to fn?  Can you take the address of something that's not assignable, like the name of a local array variable?

Comment: @Ben, inside the `fn(&a);` call, a is a pointer to an array of 3 elements. Therefore `sizeof(a)` would be the sizeof a pointer, and `sizeof(*a)` would be `sizeof(const char[3]) == 3`. In `fn2(b);`, `*a` is still a pointer (to const char), and hence you'll (typically) get different results from the two function calls.

Comment: ... you could do `const char *c = a; fn2(&c);`. `c` is now pointing to `a[0]`, which has the same address as `a`. But you'd be passing a pointer to `c` into fn 2, which is still neither the same value as a pointer to `a`, nor the same value as 0. `a[0]` has the same address as `a` but different type, so inasmuch as different pointer types are comparable, `&a[0]` has the same value as `&a` but is of a different pointer type. For a function to accept either `&a` or `&a[0]`, it would have to take `const void*`, and then it would receive the same value for both.

Comment: @Ben, yes you can take the address of a `const` variable. The variable still takes up space in memory, and hence has an address even if you told the compiler not to let you modify it.

Comment: @Ben: you can take the address of any lvalue. An array is a non-assignable lvalue. An integer literal is an rvalue, which is why you can't take the address of it.

Comment: @Steve, ok, that clicks for me.  So, if I called `fn3(*c)` where `fn3` takes a `const char (&d)[3]` parameter, then I could use that parameter `d` syntactically just as if the parameter were declared `const char d[3]`, although in the first case `&d == c` and in the second case `&d` is just the address of the argument that was pushed onto the stack, so `&d != c`.

Comment: You can't call `fn3(*c)`, because `*c` is a `const char`, not an array of 3 const chars. It happens to be *part of* an array, but that doesn't count for anything. But as you surmise that is "just" because of type-safety, "really" `*c` is at the same address as `a`. Within the function `d` is as you say, the same type as if declated `const char d[3];`. But in that function `&d` is not the address of anything used in the calling convention, it is the address of the array to which that reference argument refers. You can't take a pointer to a reference: only to its referand.

Comment: @KTC, `const` is not the issue.  If you have a local variable `int arr[3]` (no `const`!), that only makes space on the stack for three `int`'s.  The identifier `arr` itself doesn't have an address.  That's why you need to do `int* c = arr;` and then take the address `&c`, as in Steve's trick.

Comment: @Steve, thanks for seeing through my mistakes :)  What I should have said was to do `const char **cp = &c;` and then call `fn3(*cp)`, which works because you can assign `*cp` (or `c`, for that matter) to a `const char (&)[3]`.  *Then* `&d == &c` and therefore `&d == cp`.  This might be getting away from the original question, but it's been really helpful for me!

Comment: @Ben: Nope, you can't assign `*cp` to a `const char(&)[3]` either. Again, the type system in action :-) `*cp` is a `const char*`, and while an array of 3 const char can be converted to a `const char*`, not every `const char*` points to an array of 3 const chars. It might only point to 1 for all the type system knows. So the conversion array -> (ptr to first element) is one way only. I suggest you write some of this code and see what compiles and what doesn't - if you keep these questions up long enough I *will* eventually get one wrong, which will just be confusing for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way that a function can be made such that the size of the array is passed into the function automatically.

```
static_strlen(const char (&str)[Len])
```

is a function that takes in an array of `const char` of exactly `Len` elements. The array size must be known at compile time. I.e. the array wasn't allocated via new or malloc.

To be more specific, the parameter is a reference to an array of `Len` elements, rather than an actual array, which is why it doesn't get converted into a pointer when passed.